# Private property in class implementation

Tags: typescript

There is an interface implementation:

```
interface ISome {
    some: Function;
}

class Awesome implements ISome {
    constructor(private some: Function) {}
}
```

This triggers an error:

> Awesome incorrectly implements interface ISome . Property 'some' is private in type 'Awesome' but not in type 'ISome'.

But adding `private` to ISome is not possible,

```
private some: Function;
```

triggers

> property or signature expected

How this should be treated?

Comment: You'll need to write it out the old-fashioned way, declaring the `private some` property in the class, and assigning it in the constructor with `this.some = some;`.

Comment: Interface declare a public contract, there's no way to have non-public definitions in an interface (and that's true for most if not all OO languages). If you want your class to have a private method/member then it should not be part of the interface. What is your exact problem?

Comment: @NitzanTomer The remark on interfaces makes sense. `some` member (a callback provided through DI) is not a part of public interface and is used internally. But it is expected to exist in ISome implementations (at least for testing purposes), so I would like to force its presence via interface. I guess that inheriting from `protected abstract some()` is suited to the case, though I would prefer to save `extends` for concrete parent, not abstract. Looks like there's no good answer.

Comment: In OO what you're describing is meant to be done using a protected abstract method. Interfaces can never expose inner functionality. You should have the `ISome` interface and then a `BaseSome` abstract class which has this `protected abstract some` method. Even if you did have a way to force that on the interface I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: Thanks, that was my second thought, the explanation is quite clear. Feel free to paste the comments as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How this should be treated?

I'd say by questioning intent and/or some of the assumptions.

> Awesome incorrectly implements interface ISome . Property 'some' is private in type 'Awesome' but not in type 'ISome'.

Private properties can not serve as implementation for the interface. `Private` means it's not accessible outside of the class, so if you have

```
class Awesome {
    private some: Function
}
```

you can't pass instance of that class to

```
function doSomething(awesome: {some: Function}) { ... }
```

because there is no way it can get `some` which is private in Awesome.

Looking from another side, if you want `some` to be private, what's the point of exposing it in the interface? Private property is not accessible outside the type that declared it, but there is nothing in the interface that could have access to it - interface is a contract, it contains no implementation.

What is the intent of the interface? To make sure that particular class has particular private property? But how is just having private implementation in the class not sufficient?

Or, was the purpose to have some public property, backed by private implementation? Then this would suffice:

```
interface ISome {
    some: Function;
}

class Awesome implements ISome {
    public some: Function;

    constructor(private someImpl: Function) {
        this.some = someImpl
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've explained the reasoning behind this in comments. `some` member (a callback provided through DI) is not a part of public interface and is used internally. But it is expected to exist in ISome implementations (at least for testing purposes), so I would like to force its presence via interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to make a given method "un-overridable" by extension classes, you can add some assert code to the class's constructor which verifies that the methods have not been modified for the new instance.

It's not ideal (eg. it's run-time rather than compile-time), but it's the next best thing that I'm aware of.

Example:

```
function HasSealedProps(target: Object) {
    let oldConstructor = target.constructor;
    target.constructor = function() {
        for (let key in target["prototype"]) {
            let method = target["prototype"][key];
            if (method.sealed) {
                console.assert(this[key] == method, `Cannot override sealed method "${key}".`);
            }
        }
        return oldConstructor.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
function Sealed(target: Object, key: string) {
    target[key].sealed = true;
}

interface MyInterface {
    DoNotOverrideMe: Function;
}
@HasSealedProps
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    @Sealed DoNotOverrideMe() {
        console.log("I shall always exist. No one shall take my place.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the question was about how to guarantee that private/protected method will be implemented in the class by means of TS. It doesn't say anything about overriding.